# How to create a backslash fraction?

Tags: fractions

How does one produce a backslash fraction? That is, something like `2\1` with the 1 above the 2.

Comment: Please draw a picture.

Comment: Do you mean `\frac{1}{2}`, using [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) ?

Comment: Interesting idea, but also (I'm just curious) why would you write a fraction this way?  I spend so much time in classes trying to get the students not to use a slanted lines for fractions 'cause it inevitably leads to all sorts of mistakes.  Or, does it have special meaning?

Comment: @A.Ellett I think it was the musical time-signature notation used by that famous American composer, Burt Back-a-frac. `;^)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I chose to use math mode to set the argument of `\bsfrac`, even though I notice that `\nicefrac` sets in text mode.  The behavior can be changed for `\bsfrac` with the removal of the `$` characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,nicefrac}
\newcommand\bsfrac[2]{%
\scalebox{-1}[1]{\nicefrac{\scalebox{-1}[1]{$#1$}}{\scalebox{-1}[1]{$#2$}}}%
}
\begin{document}
A nice fraction: \nicefrac{55}{23} or \nicefrac{$(x-1)$}{$x$}.

And here is \bsfrac{55}{23} or \bsfrac{(x-1)}{x}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can simplify the definition as

```
\newcommand\bsfrac[2]{\reflectbox{\nicefrac{\reflectbox{$#1$}}{\reflectbox{$#2$}}}}
```

or even, as Máté suggests,

```
\newcommand\bsfrac[2]{\reflectbox{\nicefrac[\reflectbox]{$#1$}{$#2$}}}
```

Comment: Oh, that's what the `bs` stands for...

Comment: @MCMastery Apparently, my efforts to use mnemonic devices to name macros sometimes can be misunderstood...http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167670/umlaut-dots-in-a-different-color/167674#167674

Comment: You can even further shorten the definition of `bsfrac` to `\newcommand{\bsfrac}[2]{\reflectbox{\nicefrac[\reflectbox]{#1}{#2}}}`

Answer (score 6):

A shorter less elegant way is to simply use:

```
$^1$/$_2$ %or
$_1 \backslash ^2$
```