# How can I write a reflected \sqrt operator?

Tags: symbols

[image]

How can I produce this symbol in LaTeX? It is used in Galois theory for *p*-adic fields to denote a root of the equation *X^{p}-X-a* with *a \in k*, and being *k* a *p*-adic field. I have tried a lot of different things like rotatebox or reflect box, but I can't produce the same output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Are *p* and *a* part of the symbol (what does it denote, by the way)?

Comment: If I could obtain a command (for instance named "modified") and obtain the output writing \modified[p]{a} it would be nice, but it doesn´t matter really, I only need to obtain the same output.

Comment: It´s usually used in Galois theory of p-adic field, to denote a rooth of the equation $X^{p}-X-a$ with $a\in k$, and being $k$ a $p$-adic field.

Comment: Will *a* always be  a single letter or may it be a longer expression?

Comment: It will always be a single letter

Comment: if this is an "accepted" symbol (i.e., it has appeared in a publication reviewed for mathscinet), and you can provide a citation of where it appears, i can submit it to be considered for inclusion in unicode.  the best documentation shows the symbol in a context that clarifies its meaning and usage.

Answer (score 26):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\reflectsqrt[2][\relax]{
  \ifx\relax#1
    \scalebox{1}[-1]{$\sqrt{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$#2$}}$}
  \else
    \scalebox{1}[-1]{$\sqrt[{\scalebox{1}[-1]{%
      \raisebox{-4pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}}]{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$#2$}}$}
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
$x\reflectsqrt{a}$

$x\reflectsqrt[p]{a_3 + b^3}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @matemagreek please accept the answer if you think it solved your problem :-)

Comment: It even works with `$\reflectsqrt[p]{\frac{x}{y+1}}$`

Comment: I think using `\ifx #1\relax` is a little safer than `\ifx\relax #1`.

Comment: @Werner Why would that be?  I am always reminded that doing an if-test using `#1` first allows for false positives if, for example, `#1` is specified as `11`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: True. I think best would be to use one of the techniques in [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764) or [What's the best practice way to test whether parameter is empty?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263733/5764)

Comment: @Werner I see my test along the vein of (but not quite the same as)`\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax`.  In my flavor of the test, the only failure I see is if the optional argument is a macro whose expansion begins with `\relax`.  I'm still trying to imagine a valid invocation scenario where that actually could occur...

Comment: @Werner Perhaps Heiko's example of `\ifx\TestEmptyFence#1\TestEmptyFence` would be best...

Comment: @samcarter I used the same double-reflection trick here, except about the vertical axis: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334813/how-to-create-a-backslash-fraction

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I would upvote your other answer if I had not already done so :)

Answer (score 6):

With `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength\rlength

\newcommand\padicroot[2]{\settowidth{\rlength}{\ensuremath{\,#2}}%
\stackMath\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.3ex}{\scriptscriptstyle#1}%
{\raisebox{-0.6ex}{\Large$\wedge$}}\mkern-2mu\rlap{\rule[-0.68ex]{\rlength}{0.5pt}}%
\mkern1mu#2}

\begin{document}

\[ \padicroot{p}{y} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hoist by my own petard!  +1

Comment: I must say I was surprised you didn't use your own package ;o) I also thought of a solution like yours, but finally opted for this one as more flexible.

Comment: You should edit your answer so that it does not require rightward scrolling.  Just sayin'