# Writing quotients properly

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

When writing the quotient with respect to, say, a group action, the notation is X/G, and in latex, this compiles to look almost the same as X/G. The problems come when writing the quotient w.r.t. a left action, in which case it is G\X. I thought for the longest time that the author(s) were writing some kind of set difference and that either I or them had confused things.

Ideally I would like X to be slightly elevated above the slash, and G to be slightly lowered below, but keeping the distances in check (nothing like X  /  G just for the sake of elevating/lowering).

Does anyone know of any good tricks or methods to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for  `$X\setminus G$` ?

Comment: There is quite a difference between `G\backslash X` and `G\setminus X`. Readers accustomed to the notation for group actions will not be bothered by the former (the latter means set difference).

Comment: Is this question related:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334813/how-to-create-a-backslash-fraction ?